# trigger to edit other table in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers, syntax-error

I have the following trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_day_1_status_update$$
USE `tbl_user_status`$$
    CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `tbl_user_status`.`trg_day_1_status_update` AFTER INSERT ON `tbl_tf_day_1` FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    UPDATE tbl_user_status
        SET NEW.roadmap_day = tbl_tf_day_1.roadmap_day,
        SET NEW.user_status = "active",
        SET NEW.latest_submit = tbl_tf_day_1.submitted_on,
        SET NEW.latest_tf_id = tbl_tf_day_1.tf_id,
        SET NEW.d0 = 1,
        SET NEW.latest_cig_intake = tbl_tf_day_1.q_id_3_ftnd,
        SET NEW.latest_cigintake_submit = tbl_tf_day_1.submitted_on
    WHERE id_user = tbl_tf_day_1.id_user LIMIT 1;
    END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But I keep getting an error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET NEW.user_status = "active",
        SET NEW.latest_submit = tbl_tf_day_1.submitted' at line 5
```

I've tried a bunch of stuff, including removing the 'NEW' before the fields, changing the value to be inserted, and even making this trigger BEFORE the insert. Can't figure out what's wrong, please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things wrong here, set only needs to be stated once, the direction of the set statements is incorrect , the column to the left of the equals (=) should the the column you wish to set in the table you wish to update and the column to the right of the equals (=) should the the column you wish to update it from pre- ceeded by a NEW. qualifier (but not for constants such as 'active', the where clause column name to the right of the equals (=) should be preceeded by NEW. I am also a bit dubious about the table name you are trying to update which seeems to share a name with the db/schema in your create statement.

Comment: You were right about the table name, but the trigger was being used to update a different table from the one where the insert originally occurred. In any case, with the SET fix, I was able to include this little snippet in a different trigger occurring before the insert. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use the `SET` keyword once, then comma-separate the fields, like this:

```
UPDATE tbl_user_status SET
    NEW.roadmap_day = tbl_tf_day_1.roadmap_day,
    NEW.user_status = "active",
    NEW.latest_submit = tbl_tf_day_1.submitted_on,
    NEW.latest_tf_id = tbl_tf_day_1.tf_id,
    NEW.d0 = 1,
    NEW.latest_cig_intake = tbl_tf_day_1.q_id_3_ftnd,
    NEW.latest_cigintake_submit = tbl_tf_day_1.submitted_on
WHERE id_user = tbl_tf_day_1.id_user LIMIT 1;
```